# How to create a TCP receiver using Akka Java API that doesn't respond

Tags: java, tcp, streaming, akka

I am using this [example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/stream/stream-io.html#Accepting_connections__Echo_Server) as my starting point.

In that example, server responds with the modified text but in my case, server doesn't need to respond.

Looking at other similar questions, I am aware that I can either pass Empty ByteString or use filter(p -> false) to not send anything back. However, in that case, the problem is that my whenComplete block doesn't get executed. i.e. the exception gets swallowed. Is there a way to avoid this? Help appreciated on this !

```
connections.runForeach(connection -> {
System.out.println("New connection from: " + connection.remoteAddress());

final Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> echo = Flow.of(ByteString.class)
.via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString("\n"), 256, FramingTruncation.DISALLOW))
.map(ByteString::utf8String)
.map(s -> s + "!!!\n")
.map(ByteString::fromString);

connection.handleWith(echo, mat);
}, mat).whenComplete((done,throwable) -> 
    { 
    //exception handling
    }
);
```

Comment: On further analysis, I think the issue is that I want to get a completionStage for each Connection and not at the end of Source (connections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, now you are reacting when the server shuts down rather than each connection.

Reacting on the individual connections completing would be done in the flow passed to the connection, something like this:

```
final Tcp tcp = Tcp.get(system);
tcp.bind("127.0.0.1", 6789).runForeach((connection) -> {

  final Flow<ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed> echo = Flow.of(ByteString.class)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString("\n"), 256, FramingTruncation.DISALLOW))
    .map(ByteString::utf8String)
    .map(s -> s + "!!!\n")
    .map(ByteString::fromString)
    .watchTermination((notUsed, completionStage) -> {
      completionStage.whenComplete((done, exception) -> {
        System.out.println("Connection from " + connection.remoteAddress() + " completed");
      });
      return notUsed;
    });

  connection.handleWith(echo, materializer);
}, materializer);
```